# Debian package difference e.g. +squeeze3

Tags: debian, apt

I have about 200 Debian servers and started the job to ensure all packages on the box are the same (per environment).

However, across my environment I get slightly difference package names like the below:

2.6.2-5, 2.6.2-5+squeeze3, 2.6.2-5+squeeze1, 2.6.2-5+squeeze6, 2.6.2-5+squeeze4

As you can see all the puppet packages installed are 2.6.2-5 - so what is all this +squeezeN?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The version in these cases refers to an NMU or other similar minor update. The upstream version is the same but the actual package versions are in fact different. You might want to examine `/usr/share/doc/puppet/changelog.Debian.gz` for +squeeze4 to see what exactly [changed](http://packages.debian.org/changelogs/pool/main/p/puppet/puppet_2.6.2-5+squeeze6/changelog).

In general, 1suffix in a Debian version number is always larger than just 1, with the exception that 1~suffix is always smaller.

If the upstream version is 1.23 and the Debian package of that version is the fifth upgrade, the Debian version number is 1.23-5. For very minor updates which do not warrant a whole-number increment of the Debian part, you'd often see something like 5.1 or 5descriptivetag1. Forks, derivatives, etc might use something like 1.23-5ubuntu3 to tag their third version of Debian version 5.

The `+squeeze` part indicates that these versions are minor updates to the stable version originally shipped when Debian Squeeze was published. Debian's policy is to not ship new versions of packages in the stable distribution, with the exception that they will accept critical, well-defined, limited fixes (generally patches for security vulnerabilities).

Comment: Thanks tripleee, so just to confirm - 2.6.2-5+squeeze1 is actually different to 2.6.2-5+squeeze6, albeit rather minor..

Comment: Oops, found a better link. Those updates are actually pretty crucial! You should subscribe all your production systems to the debian security updates repo and do an Apt upgrade regularly.

Answer (score 0):

those versions relate to post-release uploads.

usually packages will be frozen once a release (like `squeeze`) has been done. after that, usually only updates that fix security-related issues are allowed to get uploaded.
these uploads get an additional -tag in the version, so 2.6.2-5+squeeze6 would be the 6th upload to squeeze after it's release.